# Multiple tables based on value of column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SELECT
Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM
sometable

I need to build a report in SSRS with multiple tables. The tables are dependent on Field1 being filtered to only show one value per table. If the value isn't selected. Then I don't want to see the corresponding table. Can this be done?

Comment: How many values are there in Field1? Please explain your scenario in more detail.

Comment: 8 different values so 8 different tables unless one of the values turns out to be null. I know I can repeat my sql code 8 time but this will be applied to multiple sites so the number of values in "Field1" may be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Table **visibility** based on the number of rows in the dataset results:

```
=CountRows("Dataset1") <> 1
```

Seems a bit hacky though.

There may be better solutions but we would need more info on what you're doing.